# EKEventStore.fetchReminders is very slow using it the first time

Tags: swift, macos, calendar, eventkit

On macOS I'm loading reminders using EventKit. Everything works, but when loading the reminders for the first time during runtime, it takes way longer than after that. This means the user has to wait after starting the app to see any reminders, which is not so nice. The native Reminders app works faster.

Here is some code:

```
import Cocoa
import EventKit

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        testReminders()
    }

    func testReminders() {
        let eventStore = EKEventStore()
        let incompletePredicate = eventStore.predicateForIncompleteReminders(withDueDateStarting: Date(), ending: Date(), calendars: nil)

        // Get the access permission first
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder, completion: { (granted, error) in
            // Now test
            self.semaphore.signal()
            for _ in 0..<10 {
                self.startMeasuring(eventStore, predicate: incompletePredicate)
            }
        })
    }

    func startMeasuring(_ eventStore: EKEventStore, predicate: NSPredicate) {
        semaphore.wait()
        let start = DispatchTime.now()

        // Get the reminders
        eventStore.fetchReminders(matching: predicate, completion: { (incompletedReminders: [EKReminder]?) -> Void in
            let end = DispatchTime.now()

            // Print out the elapsed time
            let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
            let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000
            print("elapsed: \(timeInterval)")

            self.semaphore.signal()
        })
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

If you are running above code, make sure you checked "Calendar" in the "App Sandbox" Capabilities.

Here is the output in seconds:

> elapsed: 9.322825215
>   elapsed: 0.045737709
>   elapsed: 0.036359244
>   elapsed: 0.03218976
>   elapsed: 0.044998467
>   elapsed: 0.034777283
>   elapsed: 0.032737581
>   elapsed: 0.04387221
>   elapsed: 0.03941968
>   elapsed: 0.044008471

9 seconds is way too long. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and it seems the Reminders sqlite database needs a vacuum / analyze. I was getting 12 seconds per fetch every single time till I did this:

```
cd ~/Library/Reminders/Container_v1/Stores

sqlite <each .sqlite here>

VACUUM;
ANALYZE;
.quit
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for posting this. For me, meanwhile, the situation seems to have improved by some macOS updates. I'm not sure if I can still reproduce it. Since it wasn't recently a problem anymore, but super interesting to see learn how Reminders works under the hood (with sqlite)